# python multithreading - confused with output

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, python-multithreading

I am trying to create a multithreading program that will run one thread for three seconds, then 'pause' the thread using event objects, wait for a few seconds, then repeat the process over again. here is my code:

```
import threading
import time

counter = 1 

def control():
    global counter
    test_event.wait()
    while(test_event.is_set()):
        print 'waiting 3 seconds'
        time.sleep(3)
        event.set()
        time.sleep(3)
        event.clear()
        if(counter == 1):
            counter = counter - 1

def function():
    global counter
    event.wait()
    while (event.is_set()):
        test_event.clear()
        print 'event is set to high'
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'event is set to low'
    test_event.set()

event = threading.Event()
test_event = threading.Event()

t1 = threading.Thread(target = control)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = function)

t1.start()
t2.start()

while(counter == 1):
    test_event.set()
```

the output I am desiring should look like this:

```
waiting 3 seconds
event is set to high
event is set to high
event is set to high
event is set to low
waiting 3 seconds
event is set to high
....
....
and that keeps repeating.
```

the output I am currently receiving however is this:

```
waiting three seconds
event is set to high
event is set to high
event is set to high
waiting 3 seconds

event is set to low 
waiting 3 seconds
waiting 3 seconds 
waiting 3 seconds
...
...
and that keeps repeating.
```

Can anybody detect where I am messing up, and possibly offer any advice for me to fix? I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

P.S. I am aware that this code probably is constructed very poorly, but I am completely new to multithreading...sorry in advance!

Comment: There are a number of issues with this, which makes it hard to answer. Just presenting wokring code is also not helping as much as you understanding what is going on, I think. So, let's start with one thing you may overlook, which affects the program. You actually have three threads. In addition to the two you create, there is also a main thread. What happens with main? Well, when`counter` becomes 0 (set by the `control` thread) it will just leave the `while` loop and be done, This is probably not what you want, right?

Comment: apologies, I wrote my post incorrectly. I understand there are 3 threads, a main thread, a t1, and t2. My intended purpose for the main thread is to simply 'activate' the t1 thread (I know this is probably inefficient but I am just trying to get a working code right now. I will focus on making it better at a later time). my goal is to 'cycle off' between t1 and t2 (as the function names suggest, I want the control function to basically act as a switch for the function thread)....does this clear up any confusion?

Comment: No worries. Next probelm is then that your two threads `control` and `function` may (and does) run to completion. When either of the `while`clauses are `False` there is nothing to restart the threads. In situations like these, you typically want the threads to run forever, or to some external condition makes them break out of exectuion.

Comment: okay, I added on a 'while True:' argument to both of functions I created, and cleaned up some of the time.sleep() commands and it seems to be giving me the output I am looking for... thanks much for the help!

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't be using these low-level, dangerous threading primitives as your first steps into multithreaded programming.